# Absorted (core dumped) emacs

Tags: gtk

When runing emacs, the machine aborted every 1~3 hours.

```
Backtrace:
emacs[0x51159e]
emacs[0x4f6f6a]
emacs[0x511643]
emacs[0x4574ea]
emacs[0x459c45]
emacs[0x5ab860]
emacs[0x5b35f5]
emacs[0x4f6d34]
emacs[0x4c3efd]
emacs[0x4c4037]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(_XIOError+0x4e)[0x7f0236e6a0de]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(_XEventsQueued+0x7d)[0x7f0236e6799d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(XFlush+0x1a)[0x7f0236e4950a]
emacs[0x4e08d6]
emacs[0x4fda17]
emacs[0x4fe42d]
emacs[0x500e5a]
emacs[0x5049a0]
emacs[0x5060a4]
emacs[0x56cd9e]
emacs[0x4f7344]
emacs[0x56cd0d]
emacs[0x4f72db]
emacs[0x4fc363]
emacs[0x4fc6a8]
emacs[0x41a631]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xeb)[0x7f0234ffbb6b]
emacs[0x41b2ea]

[1]+  Aborted                 (core dumped) emacs
```

The machine infos

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:        19.04
Codename:       disco
```

Is it possible to solve the problem?

Comment: What are you doing in Emacs when it crashes? What plugins/extensions do you use?

Comment: I am using doom-emacs.  @SurvivalMachine